# Como usar os valores de uma coluna presente na Tabela A como parâmetro WHERE de um SELECT na Tabela B?

Tags: php, sql, moodle

É possível fazer com que a consulta SQL `$professores` seja feita com base no ID `$row["id"]` da 5ª linha do código abaixo?

*Contextualizando: este código exibe uma lista com cursos presentes em um BD, imprimindo o nome e o ID do curso, com seu(s) respectivo(s) professor(es) - caso existam. Entretanto, essa consulta de professor deve ser feita com base no papel que um professor tem dentro de uma disciplina (o que é feito com o comando `$professores`, mas essa consulta só está funcionando se um valor manual de ID for acrescentado, sendo que o ideal é que tudo isso seja dinâmico, por isso o interesse em usar o `$row["id"]` como parâmetro).*

Grato desde já!

```html
$cursos = "SELECT id, fullname FROM mdl_course WHERE visible=1";
    $resultCursos = $conn->query($cursos);
    $row = $resultCursos->fetch_assoc();
    
        while($row = $resultCursos->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<a href="http://meu-site.php?id='.$row["id"].'" target="_blank">';
            echo '<p class="h6">'.utf8_encode($row["fullname"]).'</p>';
            echo '<p class="professor"> Professor: ';
                            
            $professores = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mdl_user WHERE id IN(SELECT userid FROM mdl_role_assignments WHERE contextid IN (SELECT id FROM mdl_context WHERE 

/* instanceid='ESSE VALOR DEVE SER IGUAL AO ID DO CURSO QUE APARECE NA 5ª LINHA' */

AND contextlevel=50) AND roleid=3)";
            $resultProf = $conn->query($professores);           
            $row2 = $resultProf->fetch_assoc();                                                     
                            
                if ($resultProf->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo utf8_encode($row2["firstname"]). ' '.utf8_encode($row2["lastname"]).", ";
                } else {
                    echo "Sem professor cadastrado.";
                }
            
            echo '</p>';
            echo '<span>Acessar</span>';
            echo '</a>';                            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei descobrindo como fazer isso!

Setei a seguinte variável:

```
$iddocurso = $row["id"];
```

E no comando SQL, usei:

```
instanceid='$iddocurso'
```

Funcionou!